# left of '.colorBet' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, class, struct, compiler-errors

Trying to access a struct member in class Hand with the following error: error: C2228: left of '.colorBet' must have class/struct/union

hand.h

```
    #ifndef HAND_H
#define HAND_H

#include"deck.h"
#include <QVector>
#include <QString>

struct street
{
    QString colorBet;
    int colorBetSize;
    int payout;
};

class Hand
{
    QVector<card> cardVector;

public:

    Hand(QVector<card> vCards);

    bool isFlush();
    bool isAllRed();
    bool isAllBlack();

    street street1;
    street street2;
    street street3;

};

#endif // HAND_H
```

mainwindow.cpp (error near the bottom)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "hand.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::build_radios(){
    street1BetBlack = new QRadioButton("Black");
    connect(street1BetBlack, SIGNAL(clicked()),
              this, SLOT(street1BetBlackClicked()));
    street2BetBlack = new QRadioButton("Black");
    connect(street2BetBlack, SIGNAL(clicked()),
              this, SLOT(street2BetBlackClicked()));
    street3BetBlack = new QRadioButton("Black");
    connect(street3BetBlack, SIGNAL(clicked()),
              this, SLOT(street3BetBlackClicked()));


    street1BetRed = new QRadioButton("Red");
    connect(street1BetRed, SIGNAL(clicked()),
              this, SLOT(street1BetRedClicked()));
    street2BetRed = new QRadioButton("Red");
    connect(street2BetRed, SIGNAL(clicked()),
              this, SLOT(street2BetRedClicked()));
    street3BetRed = new QRadioButton("Red");
    connect(street3BetRed, SIGNAL(clicked()),
              this, SLOT(street3BetRedClicked()));

    st1bg = new QButtonGroup;
    st2bg = new QButtonGroup;
    st3bg = new QButtonGroup;


    // button groups
    st1bg->addButton(street1BetBlack);
    st1bg->addButton(street1BetRed);
    st1bg->setExclusive(true);

    st2bg->addButton(street2BetBlack);
    st2bg->addButton(street2BetRed);
    st2bg->setExclusive(true);

    st3bg->addButton(street3BetBlack);
    st3bg->addButton(street3BetRed);
    st3bg->setExclusive(true);


}
void MainWindow::street1BetRedClicked()
{
    Hand::street1.colorBet="Red";        //error on every line similar to this
}
void MainWindow::street2BetRedClicked()
{
    Hand::street2.colorBet="Red";
}
void MainWindow::street3BetRedClicked()
{
    Hand::street3.colorBet="Red";
}
void MainWindow::street1BetBlackClicked()
{
    Hand::street1.colorBet="Black";
}
void MainWindow::street2BetBlackClicked()
{
    Hand::street2.colorBet="Black";
}
void MainWindow::street3BetBlackClicked()
{
    Hand::street3.colorBet="Black";
}
```

Comment: `street1` is a non-static member of `Hand`, therefore you need to access it through a `Hand` object...

Comment: Did you mean to make `street1` etc. static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hand::street1.colorBet="Red";` & the others are illegal because `Hand::street1` isn't a `static` class member (I'm not saying it should, having `static` members should be a logic decision, not something you do to make the code compile).

What `Hand` object are you attempting to modify in, say, `street1BetRedClicked`? Do you have *any* `Hand` objects? Do you need any `Hand` objects? Do you create them in that method? Outside?

I pointed out the error, but it seems to me that the important issue here isn't the fact that the code doesn't compile, but that:

1. You don't seem to have a firm grasp on C++, perhaps you should start with something simpler.
2. You don't have a clear logic set up.

Comment: First of all yes I don't have a firm grasp, I am doing this to learn. I am using hand objects to analyze the entire hand, as in hand.isFlush. Maybe street should be a class and not a struct

Comment: @user1846123 I suggest you start off by learning C++, and begin QT afterwards. The best place to do this is by reading an introductory book.

Comment: @user1846123 it doesn't matter if it's class or struct. You speak of `hand`, but you don't have **any** hands in the code. You just defined the class, but didn't create any objects. How, then, do you expect to use hands?

Comment: when the deal is made, the cards that are dealt will be defined as a hand. So  'Hand hand1(QVector<card>);'. then I can run 'hand1.isFlush()' etc.  I am now trying to implement the bets, which are bet on each card/street that is dealt. I suppose 'hand1.street1.colorBet' makes sense. I am having difficulty with setting up the logic for this. as you can tell, I am fairly new to programming.

Comment: @user1846123 so drop Qt for now and grab a book... Why aren't you taking sound advice?

Comment: Thanks I have c++ primer I will finish going through it

Answer (score 1):

When you access `street1` like this, `street1` should be a static field of `Hand`.

If every `Hand` can have its own `street1` object, you should access the object's `street1` field and not the static field.
If you want all instances of `Hand` to share the same `street1`, you should make `street1` static.

That you don't understand these concepts and from reading your other questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14079817/319611)), I can tell that you don't know C++ sufficiently to write this program. I would advise you to first read a book on C++ or learn C++ in some other way, before you start working on your own projects.

Example:

```
Hand hand1 = getRandomHand();
Hand hand2 = getRandomHand();

hand1.street1.colorBet="Red";
hand2.street1.colorBet="Black";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare an object of type Hand:

```
Hand hand;
hand.street1;
...
```

You can also declare the street fields as static.